# Comparing differences in multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

Columns `A` and `G` are `OrderID`, each with their own `AMOUNT`, Columns `C` and `H`.

If the `OrderID` columns match, I need to compare Columns `C` and `H`**.

If they are different, then highlight the cell.   I want to use VBA for this as it's part of a larger Macro I want to add to.

[image: Example]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  there are clues in your question `if` `column(a)` and `column(g)` are `equal` then what is `the difference between c and h`

Comment: Do you want to use VBA for this because "it's a part of a bigger project" or because "that's what the assignment says you have to do"?   ...because "if this is part of a big project", you should not use VBA for this.  You should use conditional formatting. You only need to make one formatting rule.

Comment: Hold on, are you wanting to look in the whole column for a match, or just the order on the same line?  Also, you say "highlight the cell" but there are two cells highlighted in your example.  Please provide more than one example of your sample data, as well as an example of your sample result, and a bit of background of what this is about, and maybe a little about this "bigger project".

Comment: I have code that can compare 2 columns and highlight differences but I don't know how to compare against Column A and Column G (the IDs). I'm comparing Column C and H where those IDs are the same. The example I attached shows what I am trying to accomplish. The cells would be highlighted because they are different but have the same orderID/ORDERNUM. So, if Column A and Column G match, Column C and Column H should also match. If they don't, I would like to highlight them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using below code, it will loop through all lines and compare column A with column G:G if its equal then compare C & H and if is not equal then change the colour index.

Code:

```
Dim Wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lrow As Long, j As Long, m As Long, lrow2 As Long, Search As Variant, Search2 As Variant
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
lrow2 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    For j = 3 To lrow
        Search = (ws.Cells(j, 1).Value)
        Search2 = (ws.Cells(j, 3).Value)
        For m = 3 To lrow2
        If ws.Cells(m, 7) = Search And ws.Cells(m, 8) <> Search2  Then


            ws.Range("C" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ws.Range("H" & m).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        End If
    Next
    Next
```

Comment: Could also be written as `if (ws.Range("A" & j).Value = ws.Range("G" & j).Value) AND (ws.Range("C" & j).Value <> ws.Range("H" & j).Value) then`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added it into my spreadsheet and ran it without errors but the cells don't change color when there are differences.

Comment: I have tested, it working fine for me, just block the statement inside If loop and debug step by step, it will make you to understand how it works.

Comment: I think I see the issue but I'm not sure how to correct it. If the IDs are on the same row, the code will highlight the differences in Columns G and H (which is good). The problem is that IDs in Columns A and G are not always in the same row. In my attached image, ORDERNUM 121698 may appear in a different row number in Column G.

Comment: You should reframe your question, if my understanding is correct try the updated code above.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much! Sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: Glad  it worked for you......